# Pry-Remote with Pow on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pry, rack-pow

I'm busy with (finally) upgrading to Rails 4 and I've run into a problem with Pry-remote.

**Problem:**

When added `binding.remote_pry` to my code it breaks the code but when I can't get into the debugger by typing `pry-remote`. This used to work when running Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.3.

**Side note:**

When running `Rails s` instead of Pow and `binding.pry` instead `binding.remote_pry` , it falls into the debugger.

**What I'm running:**

- Pow 0.5.0
- ruby 2.1.5p273
- Rails 4.2.0
- OSX 10.9.5

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-remote'
gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'byebug'
gem 'pry-byebug'
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
pry (0.10.1)
  coderay (~> 1.1.0)
  method_source (~> 0.8.1)
  slop (~> 3.4)
pry-byebug (3.0.1)
  byebug (~> 3.4)
  pry (~> 0.10)
pry-rails (0.3.3)
  pry (>= 0.9.10)
pry-remote (0.1.8)
  pry (~> 0.9)
  slop (~> 3.0)
pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.2)
  binding_of_caller (>= 0.7)
  pry (>= 0.9.11)
```

**EDIT 1: Also tried with Specs and without pry-byebug**

- Pow 0.5.0
- ruby 2.2.1p85
- Rails 4.1.6
- OSX 10.9.5

--> Returns http://pastie.org/10054841

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue as you, maybe the same one. I was able to resolve it by uninstalling the `pry-byebug` gem (version 3.1.0 before the uninstall).

If you want to give this a try, you can remove the gem from your Gemfile and run `bundle install`. You may also need to restart your Pow server using `touch tmp/restart.txt`.

**What I'm running (for comparison):**

- Pow 0.5.0
- ruby 2.2.1p85
- Rails 4.2.0
- OSX 10.10.2

Comment: Hi Randall! That works for me only problem is that I can't do next or continue anymore, it returns the following errors: http://pastie.org/10054841 also notice edit 1 for my specs.

Comment: Right, the pry-byebug gem provides this functionality. Hopefully the issue will be corrected soon, but in the mean time I'll sacrifice those commands for the ability to step into code at all.

Answer (score 1):

In your gemfile try: `gem 'pry-byebug', '~> 1.3.3'`

With `pry-byebug 1.3.3` I was able to get `pry-remote` to work. However in the pry-remote console I was not able to see any return value and had to manually do something like this:

```
Pry.config.print = Proc.new { |output, val| output.puts "=> #{val.inspect}" }
```

Comment: This is currently the correct fix because it's a known & unresolved issue https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/issues/33