# Pry-Remote not triggered Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pry, rack-pow, byebug

**Problem:**

After upgrading to Rails 4 in another branch and trying the solution that worked last time [Pry-Remote with Pow on Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584593/pry-remote-with-pow-on-rails-4) . I'm still finding difficulty with the new Rails 4 and Pry Debugger.

**What's I'm running:**

```
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]
Rails 4.2.4
Pry version 0.10.2 on Ruby 2.2.3

  # Debugging
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-remote'
  gem 'byebug'

pry (0.10.2)
  coderay (~> 1.1.0)
  method_source (~> 0.8.1)
  slop (~> 3.4)
pry-byebug (3.2.0)
  byebug (~> 5.0)
  pry (~> 0.10)
pry-rails (0.3.4)
  pry (>= 0.9.10)
pry-remote (0.1.8)
  pry (~> 0.9)
  slop (~> 3.0)
pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.2)
  binding_of_caller (>= 0.7)
  pry (>= 0.9.11)
```

Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)

Latest version from Pow

[Full Gemfile and Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/YOUConsulting/05696bd17be78b3f5440)

**Symptoms:**

Putting binding.remote_pry in the code the code is halting but unable to go into the debugger. Debugger stays "loading" after I type pry-remote.

First pry-remote: Debugger not ready.

Second pry-remote: No answer

Third pry-remote: Keeps loading without output

Fourth pry-remote: Output when CTRL + C

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

So following the suggested post ( https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote/issues/8 ).

I've done and tried the following:

- Created .prv file with:

  Pry.config.correct_indent = false

  Pry.config.auto_indent = false
- Added "require 'pry-remote'" to main.rb
- Not running Unicorn or Nginx, so no need to update those
- Updated Gemfile to `gem "pry-remote", :require => "pry-remote"`

So with all these things done, still no difference.

**Edit 2:**

With the help of Alexey Shein, I have moved a step further. Now he goes into the debugger but I can't use `next` and `step`.

[image]

**Edit 3:**

Pry-Byebug Issue created: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/issues/78

**Edit 4:**
Split this post into [Pry Remote / ByeBug next goes into Teardown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883285/pry-remote-byebug-next-goes-into-teardown) because I think this issue is more related to ByeBug then Pry-remote.

Comment: You may try checklist in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32671475/273444

Comment: @AlexeyShein please check my edit 1

Comment: Is `pry-byebug` needed at all ? Isn't `pry-remote` is enough to do the debuggingg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pry-byebug` with [version `1.3.3`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/issues/33#issuecomment-73132288). It seems `pry-byebug` author lost interest to his project, so you may need to downgrade to an older but more stable version. I'd do the following:

```
# remove pry from Gemfile, it will be explicitly loaded by dependency of pry-byebug
# gem 'pry'     
gem 'pry-byebug', '=1.3.3'
gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'pry-remote'
# remove also `byebug`, it may give too high version of byebug than needed by pry-byebug
# gem 'byebug'
```

Now run `bundle install`. After that try to start `pow` cleanly, i.e. restart/kill all `spring` and `pow` processes.

```
$ spring stop # graceful spring stop
$ ps ax | grep '[s]pring' | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs kill -9 # force spring to quit
$ touch ~/.pow/restart.txt # restart pow
```

Comment: Thanks from your answer! Now I can go into the debugger but I can't seem to use next and step. Any suggestions for that? :) Please notice my edit 2 in the original post.

Comment: @Vinozio Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Try creating an issue in `pry-byebug` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: created issue with pry-byebug!